# Chrome empty contenteditable retaining styling

Tags: google-chrome, contenteditable

Chrome appears to be doing something odd/interesting/confusing when I have a contenteditable section within a page.
If you have a section of text that is wrapped with a `<span>` (maybe other tags, I dont know) that has a class applied to it that applies additional styling to the text (font family, color, etc) and then delete all the text in the editable section.  When you start typing again, the text looks the same as you had when you started deleting text, but seems to be styled with the raw computed CSS, rather than having a span with the appropriate classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/wS4Gp/

Any idea why this happens, or if I can turn it off?  Firefox and IE both seem to keep the span with the class in it.

This is what I start with

```
<span class="level1" style="font-weight:bold;">This is level'd text</span>
```

and this is what I end up with

```
<span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48.18181610107422px; font-weight: bold;">This is level'd text</span>
```

And the relevant CSS

```
.editable .level1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size:3em;
    font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I understand what's going on, it's trying to behave like Word and other processors that retain your styling; however, these levels are important in our editor and should be retained.  If they can't I'd rather just turn off this "feature".

Comment: Interesting. I don't know the answer. There doesn't appear to be a command available via `document.execCommand()` to change this behaviour, so you may be forced to remove these styles manually.

Comment: Webkit's styling spans are terrible. Complete nonsense. I don't know this case, but I know these spans from clipboard which implementation I recently rewrote in CKEditor and I didn't know how to get rid of them. And I've just checked that CKEditor also suffer the same problem as your editable, but it is less visible and not every styling inline element is restored after deleting its content. Interesting and worrisome behaviour :|. PS. you can always write custom delete key implementation ;).

Comment: PS. Webkit not only moves styles from stylesheet to inline elements, but also replaces `<strong>` with `<b>` :D. Someone does this intentionally ;|.

Comment: I added this ticket to bugs.webkit.org https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106110   There is also this one that I found that seems similar https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34608

Comment: Hello. Did you ever find a solution to this? (How not to retain style?) Because 3 years later, the problem seems to persist.

Comment: @AviArro, Sadly, no.  This appears to be a quirk of browsers, and apart from the bugs I filed with webkit, it doesn't look like anyone has progressed further.
I would guess that since Tim Down (the author of Rangy) and Reinmar (one of the primary devs for CKEditor) both say that there's no real way around this natively, it's not going to go away until it's a priority for Chrome et al.  And that's doubtful to happen.
Luckily, I am no longer at a position where I care about contenteditable.

Comment: This also happens if you join two block elements (such as paragraphs) via backspace or delete. https://jsfiddle.net/6emqj9az/

Answer (score 3):

One way to prevent Chrome of retaining the old computed styles of the caret position is to clear the browser selection and then restoring it (to retain the selection). This should be done after the deletion of the styled element and before new content gets inserted. Doing something on the line of the following:

```js
let selection = window.getSelection();
if (selection && selection.rangeCount > 0 && selection.isCollapsed) {
  let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}
```