# Chrome: After removed formatted text, new typed text has the same styles

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, wysiwyg, contenteditable

When I remove all content from contenteditable field, and then start typing  new text wrapped into the same tag as deleted text despite that in debugger there are no relevant elements.

Examples:

[image]
[image]

Expectable behavior is following (got in Firefox):

[image]

Could somebody help me to solve this issue?

P.S. If any extra information is needed please let me know.

Comment: According to the discussion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145970/chrome-empty-contenteditable-retaining-styling), it looks like a bug in Chrome that has been present for several years ([this bug sheet](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34608) dates from 2010). No workaround has been proposed, apparently.

Comment: I would like to play around with your code. Could you share your code so we know what WYSIWYG and what not you are using?

Comment: I guess it's because Chrome caches selected element, so add an event listener on `delete` button press and get a selection with JS, call `removeAllRanges()` or `collapse()` or `collapseToEnd()`. I hope it can help

Comment: @SergeySahakyan - I think you are correct, but I was curious, do you have any documentation for the element being cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pasting text from the font size you normally would want. This will change the font size for you. If you want to choose the font size for the entire contenteditable field, try adding that to your CSS.